# "Связаны одной нитью". Нужно ли удваивать Н?

Tags: орфография, причастия, суффиксы

Как правильно пишется:  *связа**н**ы одной нитью* или *связа**нн**ы одной нитью*?
Почему?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: связаны одной нитью. Это краткое страдательное причастие, которое всегда пишется с одним н. Но: связа**нные** одной нитью. Это полное причастие.